# What happens when an attacker gains access to the secret used to generate JWTs?

Tags: node.js, security, jwt

As I understand JWT authentication it basically works like this:

- User sends login credentials to server
- If login credentials are correct, the server issues a JWT containing the users id and username (or whatever you want in the payload to identify the user)
- This JWT is generated using an application-wide secret, which should be stored in a environment variable
- The JWT is stored by the user, for example in localStorage and send with every request to the server in the header
- The JWT from the auth header is verified using the app-wide secret. If the verification is successful we know who sends the request and if the request is authorized.

But what happens if an attacker gains access to the secret used to generate the JWTs? Isn't that like a master password? With the secret and the users id/username anyone could issue JWTs for any user and basically take over any account. Isn't that a massive flaw since one little piece of information would compromise the whole system (and not just one users account)? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: This page indicates best practices:  https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way/  "Secure the secret signing key used for calculating and verifying the signature. The secret signing key should only be accessible by the issuer and the consumer, it should not be accessible outside of these two parties."  The jwt sample code has a hard-coded secret key and many people will do the same with their code, never evaluating the practice.  And a subset of those people will then store that code in a public repository.  Thanks for alerting people to the danger, btw.

Comment: Yes, of course it should never be hardcoded and it should never be in your repo (or on Github for Gods sake)... But lets say I have several instances of my application that scales by starting new instances when needed. So I need to pass the secret into every instance of my application. That means I have to store the secret somewhere on my server, since I'm not going to start the instances manually, typing in the secret that only exists in my head. Now my question: What if somebody gains access to this secret? The whole application is basically exposed, right?

Comment: On way to make it harder for an attacker that I just thought of might be to add a random, unique to every user, string to the JWT that is stored along the users information. This could be easily read out by any attacker, but only for the account that you're signed in with currently. This way the server would immediately know if a JWT was generated on the server or not. A downside would be that every request to protected API endpoints would mean a hit on the database, querying the user table to verify the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you were into all this crypto stuff I'd suggest that you read up on the Diffie-Hellman key exchange technique.  It allows two parties to have a secure conversation without first knowing a common secret.  It utilizes PK cryptography and is essentially the following analogy:

1) I put a padlock on a box and send it to you in the postal mail.  Inside the box is a secret I want you to know, in this case a session key.
2) You receive the package and place your own padlock on the box, sending it back to me in the mail.
3) I receive the box with two locks on it and remove my own lock, sending it back to you with only your lock on it.
4) You receive the box again, remove your lock and get the contents: a session key that's never been seen to anyone else but me.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a mechanism where a JWT is integrity protected by a symmetric key, i.e. a secret that is shared between sender and receiver. That's just one option to protect a JWT, admittedly not the most secure one because it relies on a secret that could be lost or stolen on both ends. It is also not useful in situations where the sender is not able to keep a secret such as in-browser clients. It is also less manageable/scalable when there are multiple receivers where the sender needs to manage one shared secret per receiver.

There's a more secure option in using public/private keypairs to protect a JWT. In that case the JWT would be signed using a private key that is only known to the sender and only the public key is known by the receiver(s). Of course if that private key is lost, it would allow an attacker to generate arbitrary JWTs and impersonate users but since the attacker apparently already has access to the server side infrastructure, he would not even need to impersonate users to get access to the server side information.

So you are right: a JWT protected with a shared secret is often less preferred because of its security implications, but there's a better way to protect it using PKI mechanisms.